# Ending of Ready Player One - Nolan's reaction

Tags: plot-explanation, ready-player-one

Spoilers ahead! Read only if you've seen *Ready Player One*.

So Nolan has been shown an ass throughout the movie.

Although in the end when he *sees* Wade holding the egg and weeping he smiles a bit - kind of giving the impression of a self realization.

But after he is arrested by the police, he tells Fnale something, in his regular evil tone, after which Fnale punches him in the face.

So what was that little moment of positivity in Nolan back there? Was that a part skipped while filming? Or was he just too plain evil?

Answer (score 6):

It's a [rueful smile](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rueful) that he gives.  He's just played the most difficult, important video-game in the history of mankind and lost to a kid, despite throwing almost limitless resources at it.